# How to iterate accumulableCollection in scala

Tags: scala, indexing, collections

Can you give some code snippet how to iterate `acc`?

```
val acc: Accumulable[mutable.HashSet[String], String] = sc.accumulableCollection(scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String]())
```

In particular, I need to index `acc`with consecutive number. 
For example, if acc has two elements 'apple' and 'aravind' as below.

```
org.apache.spark.Accumulable[scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String],String] = Set(apple, aravind)
```

I'd like to have (like zipWithIndex, but start from 1 and order doesn't matter)

```
(apple, 1)
(aravid,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Only the driver program can read the accumulator’s value, using its `value` method.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators-a-nameaccumlinka)

So (after `acc` is actually accumulated, of course):

```
val acc1 = acc.value
Range.Inclusive(1, acc1.size).zip(acc1.toList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet!